# Run Bash script once Docker container is loaded

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, gearman

I am running a Docker through docker-composer up. Its a LAMP environment and works fine. I have a docker file where i am  installing few Apache modules and loading them. After the Docker container is loaded i want to run a bash script to install a php  library and to start a service. My bash script is below

```
#!/bin/bash

cd var/www/html/gearman-1.1.2
./configure
make
make install

service apache2 restart

gearmand -d

echo "German should be working now"
```

I want to run this script every time a docker-composer up -d command is executed so i don't have to manually do the process.

I am adding the below lines in my Docker file

```
RUN chmod +x /var/www/html/run.sh
RUN run.sh
```

The above commands are throwing errors which results in Apache server not starting. Can you please tell me what is the right way to execute a bash script after a docker is up. Location of my bash script is in var/www/html and i am mounting this location to my local drive as well.

Bash script runs fine when i run it manually through the command link after logging into the container.

Complete docker file looks like below

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Install tools && libraries
RUN apt-get -y install --fix-missing apt-utils nano wget dialog \
    build-essential git curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev zip \
    libmcrypt-dev libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-0 mysql-client \
    zlib1g-dev libicu-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libgearman-dev \
    gearman-job-server \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# PHP5 Extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install curl \
    && docker-php-ext-install tokenizer \
    && docker-php-ext-install json \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_sqlite \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install mbstring \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.5.5 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini


# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

#RUN /bin/bash "chmod +x /var/www/html/run.sh"
#RUN run.sh
```

It will be worth mentioning that i am using docker toolkit and i am on windows 10 home

Comment: You probably want to run the `make` sequence in your Dockerfile, not at container startup, so that it happens only once per rebuild and not once per startup.  But if you're looking at running a second process, a second container (and possibly a second image) is frequently a better path.  (You can't start background processes in a Dockerfile at all, and running multiple processes in a container tends to be trickier than is necessary.)

Comment: Thanks. Any resource you can point me to where i can read more about it?

Comment: Commands up to `make install` should be part of docker build process, whereas the rest of commands should be part of `docker-compuse up`. It would help if you could paste a sample of Docker file.

Comment: Edited my post to include the docker file

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to launching two processes in your container, `gearman` and `apache`. And both of them need to be configured(compiled). So you need to split your `run.sh` to two part. The first one is used for compiling the `gearman`and the second one is used for launching the `apache` and `gearman`. This is a sample `Dockerfile` and a sample entrypoint file for you:

`entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

gearmand -d
status=$?
if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Failed to start gearmand: $status"
  exit $status
fi

/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND;
```

`Dockerfile`:

```dockerfile
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Install your PHP extensions and dependencies ...

# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

# compile gearman and install it
RUN cd /var/www/html/gearman-1.1.2 && ./configure && make && make install

EXPOSE 80

ADD entrypoint.sh /var/www/html/
RUN chmod +x /var/www/html/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/html/entrypoint.sh"]
```

And your can get more information about launching multiple processes in a container from this [Docker document](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

Comment: Its giving an error  cd: can't cd to var/www/html/gearman1.1.2  Though the folder exists

Comment: @Edi0 I missed a slash character in the front of the path. so i think it will works after you change `var/www/html/gearman1.1.2` to `/var/www/html/gearman1.1.2`